# Personal Finance Management Tool (OOP version)

Tags: c++, c++11

CodeReview Community! I was hoping you'd be able to review my basic OOP program. Last year I did a strictly procedural one and now I’ve incorporated OOP techniques. Ignore the commented out piece of code. The Hungarian Notation is a requirement for my university course so please don’t criticise the fact I’ve used it. I’d like to know what I’ve done well vs what I haven’t and any suggestions in making my code better. Many thanks in advance. The following scenario is what I’ve based the program on:

> Scenario A reputable bank has asked you to create a personal finance
> management program. The program will need to be able to take the
> user's monthly wage, their monthly bills, and any weekly bills that
> they may occur. This will then be broken down to find out how much of
> their wages they will then have left to save.
>
> The user should be able to enter any amount of monthly bills and
> weekly bills. The user should also have the option to add other users
> from their household to be handled within the calculations.
>
> Once all of the relevant information has been included, an overview of
> the bills against a weekly, monthly and yearly cost should be output.
>
> Inputs User's Name (Must be more than 1) Monthly Wage (Must be more
> than 1) The different bills the user has to pay (Per Person) Outputs
> User's Name Weekly, Monthly, Yearly Wage Total Weekly, Monthly, Yearly
> Bills Total Total Spent on Bills Total left to Save 10% over and under
> the total that can be saved How much can be saved per month 10% over
> and under the total that can be saved per month

```
// Personal Finance Tool.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
//

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include "Utils.h"
class Bill 
{
private:
    std::string m_sBillName;
    double m_dMonthlyBill;
public:
    Bill(std::string sBillName, double dMonthlyBill)
    :m_sBillName(sBillName),m_dMonthlyBill(dMonthlyBill) {}
    double GetMonthlyBill() {
        return m_dMonthlyBill;
    }
};

class User 
{
private:
    std::string m_sName;
    double m_dMonthlyWage;
    std::vector<Bill>objBillsToPay;
public:
    User(std::string sName, double dMonthlyWage)
    :m_sName(sName), m_dMonthlyWage(dMonthlyWage) {}
    
    void AddBill(std::string sBillName, double dMonthlyBill) 
    {
        objBillsToPay.push_back({ sBillName, dMonthlyBill });
    }

    double WeeklyWage() {
        return m_dMonthlyWage / 4;
    }

    double YearlyWage() {
        return m_dMonthlyWage * 12;
    }

    double TotalSpentOnBills()
    {
        double dTotal = 0;
        for (Bill &objBill : objBillsToPay) 
        {
            dTotal += objBill.GetMonthlyBill();
        }
        return dTotal;
    }

    double LeftToSaveMonthly()
    {
        return (YearlyWage() / 12) - (TotalSpentOnBills() / 12);
    }

    double TotalLeftToSaveYearly() 
    {
        return YearlyWage() - TotalSpentOnBills();
    }

    double OverSaved() 
    {
        return TotalLeftToSaveYearly() * 0.10;
    }

    double UnderSaved() {
        return TotalLeftToSaveYearly() - (TotalLeftToSaveYearly() * 0.10);
    }
};

void DisplayResults(std::vector<User>& objUsers) {
    for (User& objUser : objUsers) {
        std::cout << "***" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Weekly wage: " << objUser.WeeklyWage() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Yearly wage: " << objUser.YearlyWage() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "10% over total that can be saved: " << objUser.OverSaved() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "10% under total that can be saved: " << objUser.UnderSaved() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Total left to save yearly: " << objUser.TotalLeftToSaveYearly() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Total spent on bills: " << objUser.TotalSpentOnBills() << std::endl;  
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void TestData(std::vector<User>& objUsers)
{
    objUsers.push_back({ "Jack Kimmins", 764});
    objUsers.at(0).AddBill("Water Bill", 65);
    objUsers.push_back({ "George Bradley", 332});
    objUsers.push_back({ "Jason Hill", 343 });
    objUsers.push_back({ "Sean Shearing", 374 });
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<User>objUsers;
    TestData(objUsers);
    //CreateUser(objUsers); Will need to be wrapped in a while loop if uncommented
    DisplayResults(objUsers);
    system("pause"); //Ignore this, I know using system isn't good, just to stop it
}
```

Comment: Welcome, you have a huge block of code that is commented out, do you really need it?

Comment: Probably not. I just didn’t get round to getting rid of it.

Comment: Not a problem, I have removed it for you. Remember that you can always [edit] your question for errors. But avoid doing this after a review. For example, if someone suggests you to do `x` after reading your code. You should never edit and add `x` to your code since this will nullify his review.

Comment: Hi, I don’t suppose you could give me fancy algorithm library suggestions for my code?  Such as lambda expressions.

Comment: Hey, I didn't understand what you meant?

Comment: Consider accepting any answer if it helps you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to the CR community!

## Avoid making copies for non-builtin types

As a good rule of thumb, pass large objects that you don't need to modify by a constant reference. 
This will make sure that you don't create extra copies. However, you don't need to do this for the built-in types like `int`, `float`, `char`, `double`...

If you have a variable `x`. Passing it by constant reference means `const type& x`. What you do here is basically pass the memory address, which gets copied into `x`. This way you aren't passing the whole `string` class.  But just an address in the memory, which points to an existing string class.

If you wanted something to get delivered to your house, would you give the company your address or your house?

Why `const`? This makes sure that you don't accidentally modify the value of `x`. Because if you do, the value will change everywhere.

everywhere? I mean the value you used to call the function.

```cpp
void fun(int& x)
{
    x = 5;
}

int x = 10;
fun(); // x is now 5!
```

Using `const` will tell the compiler, *"If you see me modifying this, say something so I can avoid a nightmare "*.

## [Prefer using `'\n'` over `std::endl`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/stdendl-vs-n)

`std::endl` calls `std::flush` everytime. This makes it less efficient than printing `'\n'`. They both will achieve the job here, except one will be faster.

For example

```cpp
std::cout << "***" << std::endl;
```

This calls the `<<` operator twice + calls `std::flush`. The same newline can be achieved with

```cpp
std::cout << "***\n";
```

This will be more efficient

## [Maintain consistent formatting](https://codebeautify.org/cpp-formatter-beautifier)

Your code has some inconsistent formatting. Your IDE should easily be able to format code into different styles, or even a [site like this one](https://codebeautify.org/cpp-formatter-beautifier) can do the job.

---

## Re-format code into different files

As your code grows, you will realize that you cannot have all your code in `main.cpp`. Doing that makes your code just less readable. You will find it tougher to maintain your code later on too. What if you just had `Bill.h` and `User.h`! This way every time you have a problem, you can easily navigate to these files. Moreover, your code looks much cleaner

re-formatted into separate files

## `Bill.h`

```cpp
#include <string>

class Bill 
{
    private:
        std::string m_sBillName;
        double m_dMonthlyBill;
        
    public:
        Bill(std::string,double);
        double GetMonthlyBill();
};
```

## `Bill.cpp`

```cpp
#include "Bill.h"


Bill::Bill(std::string sBillName, double dMonthlyBill)
    :m_sBillName(sBillName),m_dMonthlyBill(dMonthlyBill) 
    
    {}

double Bill::GetMonthlyBill() {
    return m_dMonthlyBill;
}
```

---

## `User.h`

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "Bill.h"

class User 
{
    private:
        std::string m_sName;
        double m_dMonthlyWage;
        std::vector <Bill> objBillsToPay;
        
    public:
        User(std::string,double);
        void AddBill(std::string,double);
        double WeeklyWage();
        double YearlyWage();
        double TotalSpentOnBills();
        double LeftToSaveMonthly();
        double TotalLeftToSaveYearly();
        double OverSaved();
        double UnderSaved();
    
};
```

## `User.cpp`

```cpp
#include "User.h"



User::User(std::string sName, double dMonthlyWage)
        :m_sName(sName), m_dMonthlyWage(dMonthlyWage) 
    {}
    
void User::AddBill(std::string sBillName, double dMonthlyBill) 
{
    objBillsToPay.push_back({ sBillName, dMonthlyBill });
}

double User::WeeklyWage() {
    return m_dMonthlyWage / 4;
}

double User::YearlyWage() {
    return m_dMonthlyWage * 12;
}

double User::TotalSpentOnBills()
{
    double dTotal = 0;
    for (Bill &objBill : objBillsToPay) 
    {
        dTotal += objBill.GetMonthlyBill();
    }
    return dTotal;
}

double User::LeftToSaveMonthly()
{
    return (YearlyWage() / 12) - (TotalSpentOnBills() / 12);
}

double User::TotalLeftToSaveYearly() 
{
    return YearlyWage() - TotalSpentOnBills();
}

double User::OverSaved() 
{
    return TotalLeftToSaveYearly() * 0.10;
}

double User::UnderSaved() {
    return TotalLeftToSaveYearly() - (TotalLeftToSaveYearly() * 0.10);
}
```

---

- What is `std::string m_sBillName;` doing in `Bill`? You have declared it `private` but you aren't using it in any of the member functions, and since it is private it won't be accessible outside either.

Answer (score 3):

## Avoid Hungarian notation

You should [avoid using Hungarian notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111933/why-shouldnt-i-use-hungarian-notation), especially if you are going to prefix everything that is not a primitive type with `obj`. It becomes really useless at that point. You also fail to distinguish between objects passed by value and by reference.

Using the `m_` prefix to mark member variables is something that is done correctly though, so no problem in keeping that.

## Why does a `Bill` have a name?

You give `Bill`s names, but you can never read back the name. It is useless information at that point. If you don't store the name, then the only thing left is the variable `dMonthlyBill`, which is just a `double`. If that's all there is to it, I would say that this class doesn't do anything usefull, and should be removed. Instead, in `class User` you can write:

```
std::vector<double> monthly_bills;
```

But, the same goes for `class User`. There's no way to get the name or the list of bills out of it. The only thing it really needs to store is the monthly wage and the sum of the monthly bills:

```
class User
{
    double m_monthly_wage;
    double m_monthly_bills = 0;

public:
    User(double monthly_wage): m_monthly_wage(monthly_wage) {}

    void AddBill(double monthly_bill) {
        m_monthly_bills += monthly_bill;
    }

    ...
}
```

## Be careful converting between time periods

You cannot blindly convert monthly wages to weekly wages by dividing by four. After all, a year has 52.1775 weeks, not 48!

Furthermore, the calculation in `LeftToSaveMonthly()` is wrong: `TotalSpentOnBills()` is already per month, so you shouldn't divide it by 12. And there is no need to call `YearlyWage()` and then divide the answer by 12 again. You can just write:

```
double LeftToSaveMonthly()
{
    return m_dMonthlyWage - TotalSpentOnBills();
}
```

## Avoid using `system()`

[Don't use `system()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107705/systempause-why-is-it-wrong) unless you really need it, it is very inefficient and not portable. In this case, you can simply write:

```
std::cin.get();
```

This might require the user to press Enter though instead of any key (if the input is line-buffered), but that should be fine.

You already write in the comments in the code that you know it is bad, but why do it anyway then?

Comment: He did mention that the Hungarian notation is a necessity for his university

Comment: @AryanParekh That's true, but I'm going to comment on everything in the code anyway, because otherwise others trying to learn from this review might get the wrong idea. And if it's required, it's still used incorrectly. I sincerely hope it was not the university that actually taught this incorrect way, but it wouldn't surprise me.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of DisplayResults, opt to overload the `<<` operator for your `User` class

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, User& const u) {
    os << "***" << '\n';
    os << "Weekly wage: " << u.WeeklyWage() << '\n';
    os << "Yearly wage: " << u.YearlyWage() << '\n';
    os << "10% over total that can be saved: " << u.OverSaved() << '\n';
    os << "10% under total that can be saved: " << u.UnderSaved() << '\n';
    os << "Total left to save yearly: " u.TotalLeftToSaveYearly() << '\n';
    os << "Total spent on bills: " << u.TotalSpentOnBills() << '\n';
    return os;
}
```

Advantages:

- No longer beholden to outputting only through `std::cout`, can output to file instead.
- Easy to read
- Enables outputting a single or multiple users
- Can now use the `std::copy` and std::copy_if-to-output-iterator if you want

Don't forget to add `friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, User const& u);` to your class!

You can also do this for the `Bill` class.

Additionally, after you split out the users

```
double User::TotalSpentOnBills()
{
    return std::accumulate(
        objBillsToPay.cbegin(),
        objBillsToPay.cend(),
        0.0,
        [](auto const & accumulator, auto const & item){
            return accumulator + item;
        });
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your edit, if you have a suggestion, I hoe you can add it to your own answer rather than to add it on my own  since it was YOUR idea, not mine :)

Comment: I would have to research about `std::accumulate`, If you have a suggestion like this one it  is fine if you suggest through the comments, however, if you are correcting bad grammar,  or making the post more readable in any way you can edit it instead

Comment: If I were to justify my edit, I had just improved the formatting of the post and added `std::`

Comment: Side note, why would you like to complicate things here with `std::accumulate`?

Comment: I'm glad you asked!

Ranges are coming, and currently most devs are only starting to dip their toes into the current Standard Library. If everyone keeps doing things "same as usual", then C++ won't improve. Second, while accumulate seems scary, it's really not. It indicates intent rather quickly, and using `reduce` is even more obvious - you're reducing a range into a single value; whether that's an accumulation, a max operation, Kadane's or the Max-Profit Algorithm, as a reader clued into what's happening. Third, you'd be surprised how often STL algorithms trivialize classes.

Comment: Seems really scary to someone who isn't familiar with STL algorithms too much, I would have to be more informed to argue about that. But does your solution have any + in terms of efficiency? Because 1 for loop is much more readble according to me

Comment: Almost all STL algorithms have the same speed or faster than their for-loop equivalent, but it's compiler dependent. Even sub-optimal STL approaches tend to be on the same time-scale. Additionally, if you use `reduce` from C++17, the compiler is allowed to parallelize everything, but your lambda must be commutative.